# Rest Assured a bit: Fail to convert a response to an array of objectsRe

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I have the following POJO class:

```
public class AdcServerGroupsResponse {

  private Object availabilityGroup;
  private String cloud;
  private Object fqdns;
  private String groupType;
  private String healthCheck;
  private String name;
  private Object scalingGroup;
  private String selectionMetric;
  private List<String> serverAddresses = null;
  private List<Object> serverSubnet = null;

//Getters\Setters
}
```

describing the following response json:

```
[
    {
        "availability_group": null,
        "cloud": "1",
        "fqdns": null,
        "group_type": "discrete",
        "health_check": "http",
        "name": "t1app1",
        "scaling_group": null,
        "selection_metric": "round_robin",
        "server_addresses": [
            "1.1.1.1",
            "1.1.1.2"
        ],
        "server_subnet": null
    }
]
```

This is the method where I try to use the response values for verification:

```
public void serverAddressesDoesntContain(String wrong_ip, String username) {

    response = UserDataMap.SINGLETON.getResponsePerUser(username);
    AdcServerGroupsResponse[] adcServerGroupsResponse = response.as(AdcServerGroupsResponse[].class);
    .
    .
}
```

When I evaluate the response object by using

```
response.getBody().asString()
```

I am getting the exact json string as above.

But after I execute the second command in the method

```
adcServerGroupsResponse = response.as(AdcServerGroupsResponse[].class);
```

and evaluate

```
adcServerGroupsResponseList.get(0)
```

I get

```
availabilityGroup = null
cloud = "1"
fqdns = null
groupType = null
healthCheck = null
name = "t1app1"
scalingGroup = null
selectionMetric = null
serverAddresses = null
serverSubnet = null
```

BTW,

```
response.getBody().as(AdcServerGroupsResponse[].class)
```

and

```
List<AdcServerGroupsResponse> adcServerGroupsResponses = response.jsonPath().getList("", AdcServerGroupsResponse.class);
```

gave me the same result...

Why is that?

Comment: Fields should be `public` not `private` in AdcServerGroupsResponse class

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that.

Comment: @Fenio Thank you for your tip. Unfortunately it didn't help. I can also say that I have other POJOs in which the members are private and it still works well.

Answer (score 1):

It was in the naming mismatches between the json properties names and the class members name. They must be identical. So, for example, instead of `availabilityGroup` in class and `availability_group` in json, the member name must be also `availability_group`.